# what are the right focus and focuseout javascript functions for dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, onchange

The following function works fine for the text inputs. How do I create a similar effect for drop downs (select)?

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity',1);
});
$('input').focusout(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity',0.6);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add 'select' in your jQuery selector:

```
$('input, select')
```

Note that because of the way focus works on select elements, the effect won't occur until the user clicks off of the select a second time (if they haven't changed the selected option).

Comment: oh I think I didn't ask my question clearly. I needed the equivalent of focus for dropdowns which I think I found the answer. I'm using .change() now.

Comment: change and focus are not the same